# Why decltype isn't implicit?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why decltype can't be implicitly added to an expression when type was expected?

```
template <class X, class Y, class Z>
auto foo(X x, Y y, Z z){
    std::vector<decltype(x+y*z)> values;  // valid in c++11/c++14
    //std::vector<x+y*z> values;            // invalid
    values.push_back(x+y*z);
    return values;                        // type deduced from expression - OK
}
```

In c++14 compilers will able to deduce function return type based on return expressions. Why this can't be extended to any 'expression -> type' conversion?

The same apply to declval, why I have to write:

```
std::vector<decltype(declval<X>() + declval<Y>() * declval<Z>())> values;
```

instead of:

```
std::vector<X+Y*Z> values;
```

Comment: Is `decltype` really that annoying to type in exchange for clearly being a type instead of taking a moment to figure out whether an expression is a type or a value?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it may introduce ambiguous parsing...

Comment: ... for very little benefit. There's already whole bunch of implicit stuff going on in C++. Explicit = good, implicit = bad.

Comment: C++ allows implicit conversions between objects in wide range of cases, which is IMHO much more dangerous than between type and value.

Comment: Try writing a full-fledged formal proposal to the standards committee and see where it takes you.

Comment: @jrok: That's too over-generalized. Or do you want to code in assembler?

Comment: There is already a somewhat similar proposal [N3601](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) (plus I have heard several times a request for `template<auto t>`) for template type argument deduction on demand. A general deduction is not possible as far as I can tell: SFINAE would be affected and [there are examples](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eb14e87a47a0c16) that seems to indicate there's no trivial and general solution.

Comment: I agree with @jrok that the "implicit conversion" of an expression to its type could lead to some hard-to-spot bugs. The expression doesn't even need to be a constant expression if `decltype` is applied.

Comment: @Deduplicator Apply common sense :) I don't like to over-generalize myself, in fact.

Comment: @Deduplicator: you are mistaking explicit for low-level. Looking past C++, Rust has taken a rather extreme point of view on the *explicit vs implicit* scale (for example explicit integer casts even in non-lossy contexts) and yet it has functional programming concepts baked in.

Comment: There are plenty of things that one could think of that the language *could* do implicitly, in theory. But in every case where it does so, it's going to lead to ambiguities and corner cases and cases where it guesses wrong, and possibly interact non-orthogonally with other implicit features. For this reason it's generally sensible to avoid introducing new implicit features unless the case for them is *really* compelling.

Answer (score 11):

If implicit addition of `decltype` would be allowed, some very common templates would become ambiguous, or even impossible to express.

---

Consider the following example :

```
struct tp 
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo() { cout << "Type parameter\n"; }   

    template<int Value>
    void foo() { cout << "Value parameter\n"; }   
};

int main() 
{
  const int x = 1;
  const int y = 2;
  const int z = 3;

  tp t1;
  t1.foo<x*y+z>();
  t1.foo<decltype(x*y+z)>(); // Oops ! different version of foo() 
  t1.foo<int>();

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Value parameter
>
> Type parameter
>
> Type parameter

If `decltype` is implicitly added to `t1.foo<x*y+z>();`, the wrong version of `foo()` is called.

- C++ policy for expressing what you do, and avoid when possible any implicit work by the compiler is IMHO a very good thing. It makes things easier to read, to understand, and to maintain.
- After all, `decltype` is only 8 letters

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e4aad76292705cf).

Comment: First, your example ill-formated because x,y,z are not constexpr. Second this may me one of rare cases when decltype will be really needed.

Comment: @p2rkw They're not *constexpr*, yet they're constant expressions.

Comment: Examples of "implicit things done by compiler": default+copy+move ctor, copy+move assignment-operator, ...

Comment: In fact in your example constexpr was implicitly added to x,y and z. GCC how dare you. :)

Comment: This example doesn't tell me that the suggested implicit conversion is impossible. It could be resolved by rules exactly as in function overloading. `foo<int>` would be an exact match to `foo<x+y*z>`, while `foo<typename>` would need a conversion.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The implicit generation was recognized a mistake though, and that is why even in C++11 the copy constructor (for example) is not generated if a move constructor is specified. There was talk of actually not generating the copy constructor automatically any longer, but it would have broken backward compatibility (something C++ is very loathe to do)... however it does demonstrate that the committee recognized this implicit generation as *an issue* rather than a solution.

Comment: @MatthieuM Do you know all the circumstances for which they wanted to suppress it?

Comment: @Deduplicator: The initial intent, I think, was to suppress it as soon as you would stray from a C struct (to retain compatibility with C); however as mentioned it would have broken too many C++ programs, so instead it only kicks in where move constructors/assignment operators are concerned since those are clearly C++11 (and thus new).

Comment: @p2rkw no, the `constexpr` specifier is not magically added. You are missunderstanding `constexpr`. `constexpr` specifies that an entity (Variable/function) is preferred to be accessible/computed at compile-time, is not an specifier to say a variable/value is a constant expression. Being a constant expression is a property of values. Think of `constexpr` as a hint for the compiler, something like "*Try to compute this at compile time*". Note, for example, parameters inside a `constexpr` function are not considered `constexpr`, even if the values passed as parameters where constant expressions.